# New ICO from PlexCoin

Tags: etherscan

I am new to this community.

I have question regarding new ICO offering from PlexCoin.  They are offering (as of Aug 7th) for sale an initial 50million coins (tokens) at start price of $0.13 USD per unit.  This is all well and good.  On their website (plexcoin.tech) they are claiming a total sold tokens of approx. 14 million from approx. 8500 buyers.  Where my questions comes in is why none of these transfers or transactions are showing up on EtherScan Token Transfers or Token Holders?  Should there not already be data showing here??  https://etherscan.io/token/0xb3203DB25a01fa7950a860B42b899Ad7Da52DDD6

Could someone from Ethereum verify that transfer of PLX are actually happening through the BlockChain to holder wallets?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: PlexCoin Confirmed Scam]

PlexCoin is a confirmed scam:

https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/comments/6mr5wg/plexcoin_the_next_cryptocurrency_confirmed_scam/

AMF issued [trading] prohibition orders against PlexCorps, PlexCoin, DL Innov inc., Gestio inc. and Dominic Lacroix in connection with their activities relating to an investment in the purchase of PlexCoin, a virtual currency.